# Making each word of input an array element

Tags: ruby

For example, say I have input like follows:

```
"   see all     of these       cool      spaces   "
```

Omit the quotes. What I'm looking for is how to turn that into an array of words. Like this:

```
['see', 'all', 'of', 'these', 'cool', 'spaces']
```

Thanks

Comment: Your input is a String. There are only a few dozen methods in the [documentation for the String class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.4/String.html). I'll bet it wouldn't take long to find one that does what you want.

Comment: Hey, Jordan! Always a fan of the sass :] I actually did look, and I found the string.split thing pretty early, but I was failing to apply it properly to get what I was looking for. Thankfully, it's been answered!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to be unkind. I'm glad you got the answer you needed. In the future you should include in your question what you've attempted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way: Use `split` (see [String#split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split)):

```
string.split
```

By default, `split` will split the string into an array where the whitespace is, ignoring leading and trailing whitespace. Exactly what you're asking for. This is the same as using the more explicit `string.split(" ")`.

Comment: Could you explain to me a little more what that code is doing? Thank you, good sir.

Comment: I ended up using string.split(" ") which seemed to have the desired effect. Any pitfalls? (Brand new to Ruby)

Comment: That's equivalent. Without a parameter it behaves as if you have passed `" "`.

Comment: @8protons So would `split` with no argument as shown.

Answer (score 1):

```
"   see all     of these       cool      spaces   ".split

#=> ["see", "all", "of", "these", "cool", "spaces"]
```

Comment: No need of a duplicate answer.

Comment: @sawa although it looks that way, I don't think it's a fair reflection. At the time of posting my answer, the other answer was much more convoluted (see edits) and was edited minutes after I had posted my answer.

Comment: I see. Sorry about that.